# Which one was the latest vmware player version that supported i7 920?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, vmware-player

I need vmware player to run on windows 10 64 bit, and a i7 920 cpu, but the latest version doesn't supports i7 920, so I need an older version, but I can't find which one was the last one supporting the i7 920.

The question is which version of vmware player was the last one which supported this processor?

Comment: "latest version doesn't supports i7 920" - Why exactly do you believe that to be the case?  VMWare does not typically remove capability to their software only improve it.

Comment: @Ramhound Because I had just downloaded the last version from vmware, and when installing, it said "this processor is not supported"

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwnBT.png) the image you see?  If that is the case then you are launching a 64-bit program on a 32-bit operating system.  We need the exact error if you want assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Intel i7 here (not the exact one above) and I have VMware Workstation V16.1.0 running with VMs installed and running.

VMware Player V16 (comes with Workstation) runs here just fine.

Get the most recent VMware Player and it should work just fine on any modern i7 machine.

V16 should co-exist with Hyper-V (newest version) but disable Hyper-V (at least temporarily) if it is enabled.

Then check the VMware Support site for your particular CPU. There may be an incompatibility with your particular machine. Make sure you have a 64-bit host machine (although VMware is a combined 32-bit/64-bit product.

Comment: My i7 is first generation of i7. You probably have a newer one.

Comment: It should still work fine. Make sure Hyper-V is disabled. Restart if you change Hyper-V and try again. V16 should work back to Windows 8 (possibly even Windows 7) with no problem. I go back with Vmware a very long time. I have VMware V16 running also here on an i5 without issue.

Comment: I added some comments in my answer to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VMWare Player 14 on my i7 920. You might need the monitor.allowLegacyCPU = "true" Tweak from https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMware-Workstation-Pro-14-Fails-To-Start-Due-To-CPU-Non-Support/m-p/506389

Answer (score 0):

VMWARE 12.5 is the last one you can run with that processor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).